# Convert timestamp (database) to DateTime (C#)

Tags: c#, ado.net, timestamp

In my SQL Server table I have a column of datatype `timestamp` and I want to convert to `DateTime` in C#.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not possible.

> "The timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not
>   preserve a date or a time."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: Depends on the DBRMS. In Sybase 12 you won't find a DateTime as type, it will always show a type called timestamp which really is a DateTime with just an other format.

Comment: @Offler: I'm assuming that the OP by SQL Server means SQL Server, not any other DBRMS. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The `timestamp` data type is an alias for `rowversion`; its a binary incrementing value, its not composed of nor based upon a date & time.

Comment: If I am correct, in fact rowversion is an alias for timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp type is not a representation of a date or time but simply a generated number that is guaranteed to be unique in the database. As such, it can't be converted directly.

The only way to perform a rough conversion would be to periodically store the current time along with a timestamp in a new table, and then select which time is closest to the timestamp you want to convert from.

Alternatively you might want to add a new column to your table of type datetime, and update this whenever a row changes.

Answer (score 0):

The Transact-SQL timestamp data type is a binary data type with no time-related values....., a timestamp is neither a date nor a time.So, you can't do..... See BOL:

timestamp:

timestamp is a data type that exposes automatically generated binary numbers, which are guaranteed to be unique within a database. timestamp is used typically as a mechanism for version-stamping table rows. The storage size is 8 bytes.